# json string to int

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am wondering how to get the Json value ?(from below JSOn I would like to get product's"Price" so that I can add into total. thank you very much.

```
{ "StatusCode": 0
, "StatusInfo": "Processed and Logged OK"
, "PageNumber": 0
, "TotalPageCount": 1
, "TotalProductCount": 1
, "PageProductCount": 1
, "Products": [
  { "BaseProductId": "54158094"
  , "EANBarcode": "3068320055008"
  , "CheaperAlternativeProductId": ""
  , "HealthierAlternativeProductId": ""
  , "ImagePath": "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/008/3068320055008/IDShot_90x90.jpg"
  , "MaximumPurchaseQuantity": 99
  , "Name": "UNAVAILABLE: Evian Natural Mineral Water 500 Ml"
  , "OfferPromotion": ""
  , "OfferValidity": ""
  , "OfferLabelImagePath": ""
  , "Price": 0.51
  , "PriceDescription": "(Unavailable)"
  , "ProductId": "258247301"
  , "ProductType": "QuantityOnlyProduct"
  , "UnitPrice": 0.004
  , "UnitType": "100ml" } ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Price` tag value is not `int` its double so use `double`,,if you want `int`

then `getInt` from jsonobject but it return `0`.due to `0.5`  values...

```
         try {
                    String str="{ \"StatusCode\": 0....";
            JSONObject objJsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray array = objJsonObject.getJSONArray("Products");

               Double d =array.getJSONObject(0).getDouble("Price");
               System.out.print(d);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: hey it is working now when i changed back to double !! thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the [`JSONObject.getDouble()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble%28java.lang.String%29) method or the [`JSONObject.getInt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{ \"StatusCode\": 0, \"StatusInfo\": \"Pr...");

JSONArray products = obj.getJSONArray("Products");
JSONObject prod = products.getJSONObject(0);

double price = prod.getDouble("Price");
```

To sum up the prices, just loop through the `JSONArray` instance.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
    sum += products.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("Price");
}
```

....

Comment: hey, i did something like that, but it is not working it always returns me "0"

Comment: i think my code is much complex than you might think cos i get the Json Object from a link, then i parsed it in an array, form that array during looping, i get the product's price ..

Comment: @ThetMonAye Then, I *think* the problem is with your JSON response or either you have a subtle bug elsewhere in your code. If you post your code I might be able to help you further.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply:) it is working now when i changed back to double